# Change annotation pin color on MKMapView when you select annotation pin

Tags: swift3, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to change MKMapView annotation pin color, when i tapped on the pin. Similarly again if i select other pin it should change the color of particular pin and rest of the pin shows in previous color only. How i do this ? I don't have any idea. Any body can help me on this.

I need to show one view below depending upon pin selection . so i am MKMapView delegate method.
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)

Comment: whats have you tried ? share your code

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709176/changing-pin-color-when-selecting-annotation-pin

Comment: @kirtimali, actually i am creating a list of pins and adding on MKMapView. i am setting tag for every pin, once you select the pin i want to change  the color of particular pin . Depending upon the pin tag i need to show some information.

i am using this function to show view , that has some information. 

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)